# Passing additional arguments through function handle to do optimization in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, optimization, cell, handle

I have a function to optimize, say f,in matlab, the function depends on variable x=(x(1),x(2))over which I want to optimize and two parameters n and c which does not need to be optimize, In other words, I have an matrix of values for n and c and I want to find optimal x values for each n and c.
Here is my code:

```
clear all;
clc;
close all;
f=@(x,n,c)n*x(1)+(x(2)+3*c)/(x(1)+c);
for n=1:10
    for c=1:20
        x=zeros(length(n),length(c));
        fun{n,c}=@(x)f(x,n,c);
        options=optimset('Algorithm','interior-point')
        x(n,c)=fmincon(fun{n,c},[0;0],[1 0;-1 0;0 1;0 -1],[40;0;40;0],[],[],[],[],[],options);
    end
end

??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in ==> forloop2 at 10
        x(n,c)=fmincon(fun{n,c},[0;0],[1 0;-1 0;0 1;0
        -1],[40;0;40;0],[],[],[],[],[],options); 
Any helps? Thank you so much!
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you didn't actually ask a Question, but here's an answer:

```
function myOptimization
clear all;
clc;
close all;

results=cell(10,20);
for n=1:10
    for c=1:20
        options=optimset('Algorithm','interior-point');
        fmincon(@(x)fun(x,n,c),[0;0],[1 0;-1 0;0 1;0 -1],[40;0;40;0],[],[],[],[],[],options);
        resultingCoordinates=fmincon(@(x)fun(x,n,c),[0;0],[1 0;-1 0;0 1;0 -1],[40;0;40;0],[],[],[],[],[],options);
        results{n,c}=resultingCoordinates;
    end
end
results
end

function f=fun(x,n,c)
f=n*x(1)+(x(2)+3*c)/(x(1)+c);
end
```

You made at least 3 errors in your original code.

First, x(n,c) = fmincon... doesn't work because fmincon returns an vector with the optimal coordinates as the first output argument. Therefore, you are trying to assign a vector to a single location in the matrix "x", which is the source of your error. I put the optimal coordinates in a cell array, so that I can store all the output coordinates. If you wanted the optimal "f-value" to be assigned to your results as a matrix, you can use [~,f(n,c)]=fmincon... .

Second, "x" is a really bad name for your output matrix, even if you wanted to save the coordinates. It may even cause you errors as it's used to represent the input to your objective function, not the optimum coordinates. Use a different name for the optimum coordinates or optimal function values, which reflects that these are results.

Third, you don't need to continuously re-allocate the output matrix/cell array each time you change your parameters. Your essentially trying to clear the results each iteration, which doesn't work if you want to save them.

I also split up your objective function to be a function, and the optimization of that function to be another.

I hope this helps. In the future, please try to define a clear question on Stack Overflow.